# Multiple Any() in one Where() clause LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to use several `Any()` in one `where()` clause ?

For example, If I need to get favourite beers, this query will do the job:

```
var favouriteDrinks = drinks
     .Where(f => favouriteBeers
     .Any(d => d.drinkID == f.drinkID));
```

But what if I need to get favourite Beers and favourite Wines ? I am looking for something like this:

```
var favouriteDrinks = drinks
    .Where(f => favouriteBeers.Any(d => d.drinkID == f.drinkID) || 
           f => favouriteWines.Any(d => drinkID == f.drinkID));
```

Comment: LINQ itself has no problem with that (once you make the 2nd one compilable), but LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities might have problems translating that into a good SQL query.

Comment: it is indeed possible, you just need to define your use case.

Comment: depends on what you use, linq to entities or linq to objects, linq to entities can't accept non primitive types expression, but it certainly valid to use multiple any, this second code `f=>` is unnecessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var favouriteDrinks = drinks
   .Where(f => favouriteBeers.Any(d => d.drinkID == f.drinkID) || 
               favouriteWines.Any(d => d.drinkID == f.drinkID));
```

Answer (score 3):

why not do it like this:

```
var favouriteDrinks = drinks.Where(f => 
                favouriteBeers.Any(d => d.drinkID == f.drinkID)) ||
                favouriteWines.Any(d => d.drinkID == f.drinkID)));
```

also you can use `Contains`:

```
var favouriteDrinks = drinks.Where(f => 
                favouriteBeers.Contains(f.drinkID) ||
                favouriteWines.Contains(f.drinkID));
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try both approaches.

Comment: looks like the second query is not valid.

Comment: @user3715778 second query should be work fine on linq2sql/linq2ef/linq2object etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Union()` and `.Join()`

```
var favouriteDrinks = favouriteBeers
    .Union(favouriteWines)
    .Join(drinks,
        x => x.drinkID,
        y => y.drinkID,
        (x,y) => y
    );
```

This will work as long as `favouriteBeers`, and `favouriteWines` are of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes Tim.Tang's second example I believe. There are several approaches in here, but if it comes down to "contains" vs "any", I prefer contains as the intention is much more clear to me.

```
var favouriteDrinks = drinks.Where(d => 
            favouriteBeers.Select(b => b.drinkId).Contains(d.drinkID) ||
            favouriteWines.Select(w => w.drinkId).Contains(d.drinkID));
```

Similarly, with the correct IEquatable interfaces implemented on your "drink" classes, you can slightly simplify too

```
var favouriteDrinks = drinks.Where(d => 
            favouriteBeers.Contains(d) || favouriteWines.Contains(d));
```